# Which of Adorno's books explains best his ideas on moral autonomy?

Tags: ethics, adorno

Which of Adorno's books explains best his ideas on moral autonomy? Can anyone provide a quick outline of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main texts as you probably know are:

> Adorno, T.W. 1973. Negative Dialectics, translated by E. B. Ashton. London: Routledge.
>
> Adorno, T.W. 1991. Minima Moralia: Reflections from Damaged life, translated by E. F. N.
>    Jephcott. London and New York: Verso.
>
> Adorno, T.W. 1998a. "The Meaning of Working through the Past", in Critical Models:
>    Interventions and Catchwords, translated by Henry W. Pickford. New York: Columbia
>    University Press.
>
> Adomo, T.W. 1998b. "Education after Auschwitz," Critical Models: Interventions and
>   This content downloaded from 86.145.37.138 on Fri, 10 Jan 2020 20:02:39 UTC
>
> Adorno, T.W. 2000a. Problems of Moral Philosophy , translated by Rodney Livingstone.
>    Cambridge: Polity Press.

But you want an answer, not a list. I nominate Negative Dialectics. In this text we find the crucial idea of **nonidentity**, hard to explain briefly but well worth exploring if you have time to read the book.

What we also find in Negative Dialectics is a reflection on **autonomy** mediated by **Kant** on the one hand and, on the other, Auschwitz:

> ... we can see the core issue in Adorno's
>    moral philosophy, namely, the new categorical imperative after Auschwitz, which
>    was the catastrophic and symbolic event in the process of Western civilization:
>
> > A new **categorical imperative** has been imposed by Hitler upon unfree
> >      mankind: to arrange their thoughts and actions so that Auschwitz  repeat itself, so that nothing similar will happen.

(Songtao Luo, Adorno's View of Life, Frontiers of Philosophy in China, Vol. 10, No. 3 (September 2015), pp. 444-456: 454; T.W, Adorno, Negative Dialectics, translated by E. B. Ashton. London: 1973: 365.)

> Without a doubt, the **Kantian formal categorical imperative**, namely, "act as if the
>    maxim of your action were to become by your will a universal law of nature"
>    (I. Kant, Practical Philosophy, translated & edited by Mary J. Gregor.
>    Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1996: 73), has been transformed here by Adorno into something with
>    social-historical concreteness. In view of the concept of nonidentity, Adorno
>    acknowledges that "it is in the unvarnished materialistic motive only that
>    morality survives" (Adorno 1973, 365, emphasis added). In other words, it is
>    only in the particular, heterogeneous, and qualitative strivings of living rightly
>    and experiencing vividly, which are ultimately imbedded in the social condition,
>    that individuals can become moral and lead a right life. In this sense, **morality is
>    to a large extent based on acting in accordance with freely adopted motives**.
>    Hence, Adomo often criticizes Kantian practical philosophy on the grounds that
>    morality, as well as freedom and the right life, cannot be solely derived from
>    reason. As Adomo argues:
>
> > The material of my feelings, therefore, and indeed everything that comes to me
> >      from outside, everything that is not me in the sense of being my own reason , is
> >      really no more than a stimulus [...] the entire construction of the categorical
> >      imperative [. . .] can only be understood if the very strange coupling of freedom
> >      and law [...] is arrived at in such a way that the principle of freedom should
> >      itself be nothing but reason, pure reason [...]. (Adorno 2000a, 70-71,
> >      emphasis added)
>
> What is at issue here is that individuals will be actually and inescapably
>    repressed and subordinated to the universal imperative of norms derived from the
>    given social system rather than from the so-called universal law of nature in the
>    Kantian sense; as Colin Hearfield puts it, the autonomous character of morality
>    "evaporates in face of this compulsive submission to conscience and social duty"
>    (Colin Hearfield, Adorno and the Modern Ethos of Freedom,. Hampshire: Ashgate
>    Publishing LimitedHearfield 2004, 23).
>
> However, the analysis above does not mean that Adomo denies the role of
>    reason and personal **autonomy** in terms of living rightly. If we supposed that life
>    after Auschwitz is life as usual, and if people think that the best way to eliminate
>    the consequences of the disaster is to forget or forgive everything and just follow
>    the mies, then "absolute identity" might be eternalized as ever. According to
>    Adomo, if the individual can survive only insofar as he or she adapts to existing
>    conditions, Auschwitz will definitely reappear: "the necessity of such adaptation,
>    of identification with the given, the status quo, with power as such, creates the
>    potential for totalitarianism" (Adomo 1998a, 98-99). In this regard, individuals
>    should keep their power to reflect, should criticize the existing state of affairs
>    **autonomously** and resolutely hold on to the memory of suffering for the Adornoian imperative of life discussed above to be implemented. Otherwise,
>    once individuals are restrained by the consumerism and money-worship
>    advocated by market-freedom and the culture industry, how can they think
>    freely, act morally, and ultimately live rightly? In particular, Adorno stresses the
>    role of education (*Bildung*) in leading a right life. It is worth noting that, in
>    Adorno's view, the premier demand upon all education is that Auschwitz not
>    happen again (Adorno 1998b, 191). Since "the more enlightened the individual,
>    the more enlightened society as a whole" (cf. O'Connor 2013, 131), authentic
>    education fosters "the power of reflection, of self-determination, of not
>    cooperating" (Adorno 1998b, 195). In short, education enlightens individuals
>    again and again, spurring them to become themselves rather than mere
>    specimens.
>
> Consequently, the right life can only be achieved by maintaining nonidentity
>    thinking, undertaken **autonomously** by free, creative individuals. As Alastair
>    Morgan implies, it is the possibility of nonidentity that is freedom, and, in my
>    view, is right life as well (A. Morgan, Alastair, Adorno's Concept of Life, London: Continuum International Publishing Group, 2007:105). Only in this way can the
>    imperative of life be substantively implemented. Essentially speaking, the
>    realization of individual's right life based on his or her personal capacity for
>    experiencing, resisting, and self-reflecting, and changes in the organization of
>    society for a freer, more just, and better world are dialectically interrelated in the
>    context of Adorno's nonidentity thinking.

(Songtao Luo: 453-5.)

Comment: so a moral imperative to avoid a repeat of the holocaust grants us moral autonomy? i was just googlng it, and reading how we may have freedom from external demands [culture] but also internal -- out concept of human nature. right?

Comment: another_name. Not ignoring your comment ! I just need a little time to frame a proper reply. Best -Geoff